# Need to by pass Location while running curl command

Tags: linux, curl

While running the `curl` command using both (credentials & without) I always get location output which is correct & due to this I get 
`HTTP/1.1 302 Found` this output but in reality application is down.
any idea/help how to by pass or check the correct output.

```
[root@VDCLP3213 ~]# curl -Ik http://grid-net.gs.ec.ge.com/GestionHeures --user (username:Password)
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 10:14:52 GMT
Expires: Wed, 01 Jan 1997 12:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private,no-store,no-cache,max-age=0
Location: https://fss.gecompany.com/fss/idp/SSO.saml2?SAMLRequest=fZHBbsIwEER%2FJfI9cRJCQRaJlMKhSLSghvbQS%2BU4S7Dk2KnXKeXva6BV6YWrPfN2ZneGvFM9Kwe318%2FwMQC64KtTGtn5IyeD1cxwlMg07wCZE6wqH1csjWLWW%2BOMMIoEJSJYJ42eG41DB7YC%2BykFvDyvcrJ3rkdGaWtlE2pwUYsRiKiFSJiOVntZ10aB20eIhp7gKd2sqy0JFj6N1PzE%2FaPsEL3VO3uuj2eCf6Gy6WlVraNT6pQEy0VO3rPxpG5EPJnuGj6eTtLdiIsk4TGI%2BI5Ps8zLEAdYanRcu5ykcTIN4yRMR9skZknGxukbCTY%2FJe%2BlbqRub2%2BkvoiQPWy3m%2FDS4hUsnht4ASlmp4TsPNhebfo2lv%2BulxQthl4fHkD56hD2xjouVdjbZkav0Jc5PXvyrOViY5QUx6BUyhzmFriDnCSEFhfL%2F%2FMX3w%3D%3D&RelayState=ss%3Amem%3A7871d5ec2f67dc36f0c796d589df7cc5f38664a8a79eb7daa3d8f80059eb8259
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-L` or `--location` option to follow redirects.

Note that this will still show the headers for all the intermediate sites, you'll need to parse out the last `HTTP/1.1` line and its following headers to get the headers from the final target.

```
$ curl -s -I -L online.bridgebase.com/purchase/pay.php
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 11:04:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 160
Connection: close
Location: https://www.bridgebase.com/purchase/pay.php
Set-Cookie: SRV=www2.dal06.sl; path=/; domain=.bridgebase.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 11:04:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u11
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=og3dirjhdi4lhtm17iav8kgm67; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: SRV=www1.dal09.sl; path=/; domain=.bridgebase.com

imac:barmar $ curl --version
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0) libcurl/7.54.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2k zlib/1.2.5 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

Comment: Tried that too, problem here its still the same output.

Comment: If the server is down, there won't be any headers from the final location. You should get an error message after it follows all the redirects.

Comment: [root@VDCLP3213 /]# curl -Ik -L http://grid-net.gs.ec.ge.com/GestionHeures
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 10:56:16 GMT
Expires: Wed, 01 Jan 1997 12:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private,no-store,no-cache,max-age=0
Location: https://fss.gecompany.com/fss/idp/SSO.saml2?SAMLRequest=fZHNbsIwEIRfJfI9MTE%2FoRaJROFQJFpQQ3vopTLJEiw5dup1Snn7mqRV6YWrPfPtzO4MRa0aPm%2FdUT%2FDRwvogq9aaeTdR0paq7kRKJFrUQNyV%2FB8%2FrjmLBrwxhpnCqNIMEcE66TRC6OxrcHmYD9lAS%2FP65QcnWuQU1pZWYYaXFRhBEVUQVSYmuZHud8bBe4YIRp6gTO63eQ7Eix9GqnFhftHOSB6q3c2Qp87gn%2Bhsmxonm%

Comment: Now application is up..but still same

Comment: I just tried it with a URL on my server and it works.

Comment: could you please share the output with me & the also curl version

Comment: Added to my answer